# How to get the nth item of a tag in HTML using VBA and selectors for export to Excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

How can I use a selector to check if the content of "alt" is "Meeting" or "Canceled"?

```html
    <body>
      <div class="mainBox">
           <li class="content">
               <img class="title" src="https://url_01/images/img01.gif" alt="Meeting">
           </li>
           <li class="content">
               <img class="title" src="https://url_02/images/img02.gif" alt="Meeting"> 
          </li>
           <li class="content">
               <img class="title" src="https://url_03/images/img03.gif" alt="Canceled">
          </li>
           <li class="content">
               <img class="title" src="https://url_04/images/img04.gif" alt="Canceled">
          </li>
       </div>
    </body>
```

**Important:** the selector MUST refer to **class="title"** because all other tags in these 4 strings occur differently often in the entire html code. Thanks

My Code:

```
Public Sub GetData()

    Dim ohtml As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elmt As Object
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set ohtml = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", "https:...", False
        .send
         ohtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
         
    For x = 0 To elmt.Length - 1
    
    Set elmt = ohtml.querySelectorAll("img[class='title']").Item(x)  '<<==  ??????
    
    If instr(????????, "Meeting") then  '<<=====  ???????
      ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = "Meeting"
    Else
      ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = "Canceled"
    End If
    
    Next
            
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `elmt` before the loop

```vb
Public Sub GetData()

    Dim ohtml As New HTMLDocument, elmt As Object, i As Integer
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", "https:...", False
        .send
         ohtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set elmt = ohtml.querySelectorAll("img[class='title']")
    For i = 1 To elmt.Length
       'Debug.Print i, elmt(i - 1).alt, elmt(i - 1).src
       ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 2) = elmt(i - 1).alt
    Next
            
End Sub
```

update1 : replace s, s2 with .responseText

Comment: (src="https://xxx.gif ) =>> xxx are variable values, hence "x". i cannot declare them in advance!

Comment: @Jasco Sorry I don't understand how the src attribute is relevant ?

Comment: How declare "s" & "s2" as you described without knowing the content of src?

Comment: @Jasco Those variables are just substitutes for the real HMTL to test the code. You would use `.responseText`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have described my problem precisely enough. Above the corrected snippet

Comment: @QHarr `elmt(i - 1)`

Comment: I apologise. It indeed compensates.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your css selector to include those additional attribute = values selectors so `elmt` only includes qualifying nodes, then extract the `alt` attribute value during the loop. And yes, set `elmt` before the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetData()

    Dim ohtml As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elmt As Object 'Dim elmt As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection '' for later mshtml.dll updates May 2021 onwards
    Dim x As Long
    
    Set ohtml = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", "https:...", False
        .send
         ohtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Set elmt = ohtml.querySelectorAll("img[class=title][alt=Canceled], img[class=title][alt=Meeting]")
    
    For x = 0 To elmt.Length - 1
      ActiveSheet.Cells(x + 2, 2) = elmt.Item(x).alt
    Next
            
End Sub
```